# While looping for multiple choice questions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

So this is what I'm trying to work with. I want Yes and No to both equal the same thing and end the loop (that I haven't started yet), though when something is typed in that isn't Yes or No it loops the question again until yes or no is inputed. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this part, I'm still learning and while loops are new ground for me.

I'm using 2.7

```
d1 = raw_input('Please answer with Yes or No.\n')
if d1 == 'Yes':
    print('Good, let\'s begin.')
elif d1 == 'No':
    print('Good, let\'s begin.')
if d1 == 'yes':
    print('Good, let\'s begin.')
elif d1 == 'no':
    print('Good, let\'s begin.')
else:
    ps('Mmmmm...')
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is Python2.7? Because `print()` from Python3. But you use raw_input - it is from Python2.7

Comment: From Python 2.7.4 onwards you can use `print()` with brackets, like in python 3.x

Comment: The `from __future__ import print_function` is implicit.

Comment: You can halve your input options by converting to lowercase...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two things to keep in mind when writing loops of any kind, and especially `while` loops are

1. What am I looping over?
2. What ends the loop? More particularly, can I know this condition immediately or do I have to run the loop first?

#1 is just the `raw_input` in this case. #2 is when `d1` is either yes or no in some form. You can not know this before getting into the loop, so you can not put it in the condition of the loop directly. This leaves you with two options:

1. Set a variable to represent the condition and initialize it to ensure the first iteration of the loop:

   ```
   found = False
   while not found:
       d1 = raw_input(...)
       if d1.lower() in ('yes', 'no'):
           found = False
       else:
           print("Mmmm")
   print("Good, let's begin.")
   ```
2. Break out of an infinite loop when your condition is met:

   ```
   while True:
       d1 = raw_input(...)
       if d1.lower() in ('yes', 'no'):
           break
       print("Mmmm")
   print("Good, let's begin.")
   ```

I think that for the simple example you present, the second option is a little more elegant. The first option is useful for more complex situations where you need to do more unrelated things before exiting the loop. It allows for three types of responses to evaluating the condition: true, false, and either. The second version only supports the first two, which is more streamlined for your case.

I would recommend putting the commands that come after the input has been processed (represented by `print("Good, let's begin.")`) outside the loop. They really have nothing to do with the loop and so should not be a part of it.

Also, use double quotes around your strings if they contain single quotes. That's a large part of the reason Python has two types of quotes.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
while True:
    d1 = input('Please answer with Yes or No.\n')
    if d1.lower() in ('yes', 'no'):
        print('Good, let\'s begin.')
        break
    else:
        print('MMMMmm')
```

Comment: As with the other answer, `if d1.lower() in ('yes', 'no'):` is a good alternative.

Answer (score 4):

You could use endless while loop:

```
while True: # Endless While Loop

    d1 = raw_input('Please answer with Yes or No.\n').upper()

    if(d1 == 'YES'):
        print('Good, let\'s begin.')
        break                           # Exits While Loop
    elif(d1 == 'NO'):
        print('Good, let\'s begin.')
        break                           # Exits While Loop
    else:
        print('Mmmmm... Do something...')
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: `if d1 in ('YES', 'NO'):` would be even better

Comment: ...or `d1.lower() in ('yes', 'no')`

Answer (score 0):

This is simple while question. try this.

```
while True:
    d1 = raw_input('Please answer with Yes or No.\n')
    if d1 in ('Yes','No'):
        print('Good, let\'s begin.')
        break
```